# Inserting data in the correct spot in a sorted mySQL table, via php/android

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post, sorting

I have found a ton of information on this subject, but its overload. I can't seem to find exactly the solution I am looking for, all I find is general stuff.

I have a mySQL table setup like this: rank | name | score

The android application only knows the name and score when inserting. I use php, and httppost to insert the data. I know how to do that. What I want to do is insert the data based on the score and have the rank assigned automatically also based on the score.

Say I have these values already in the database:

1. Tiff 1000
2. Allen 800

and I want to insert the values "Jake 900"

How do I get the resulting table to be:

1. Tiff 1000
2. Jake 900
3. Allen 800

Preferably I don't want the phone or tablet to be the thing sorting the data, because I know how to download the table, insert the info, resort it, and upload again, but I don't want the service hanging for a while even if it  is in the background.

Solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dont sort the table, sort the results of the query:

```
SELECT username, score FROM yourTable ORDER BY score DESC
```

just a a note: if you want the mySql to add the column of rank:

```
SET @rank = 0, @prev_val = NULL; 
SELECT rank, username, score 
      FROM (SELECT @rank := IF(@prev_val=score,@rank,@rank+1) AS rank,
                   username AS username,
                   @prev_val := score AS score FROM yourTable  ORDER BY score DESC)  
        AS result
```

Do not store the rank in the table because if you do, you will need to update every lower rank row in the table everytime a new score is inserted.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I will leave the column of rank off, thats easy enough for the device to add that when displaying the data. While I have programmed for years, ive never touched mySQL or php until now, its taking a little getting used to!

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use "ORDER BY DESC `score`" in the SQL query getting the results?